# HibernateException: Use of DefaultSchemaNameResolver requires Dialect to provide the proper SQL statement/command

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am running a spring boot app version 2.1.4.RELEASE.  The app is using hibernate 5.4.2.Final and postgresql driver version 42.2.5. Recently i tried to generate the DDL from hibernate in order to see the DDL, and I  stumbled upon a error that is bugging me since days.
Using the PostgreSQL 11.2 version (Ubuntu 11.2-1.pgdg18.04+1)

Now when the app is booting it is running into that exception every time.

If i place a break point on the method

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.DefaultSchemaNameResolver.determineAppropriateResolverDelegate(Connection connection)
```

i see where the exception is occurring i.e. at the point

```
connection.getSchema();
```

there are helpful comments in this class

```
unfortunately Connection#getSchema is only available in Java 1.7 and above
and Hibernate still baselines on 1.6.  So for now, use reflection and
leverage the Connection#getSchema method if it is available.

If the JDBC driver does not implement the Java 7 spec, but the JRE is Java 7
then the getSchemaMethod is not null but the call to getSchema() throws an java.lang.AbstractMethodError
```

well i am running version above 7 i.e. :

```
java -version
openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)
```

I am still running into the following exception on spring boot start i.e. !!!! EVEN BEFOR THE PART OF THE CODE (BEANS) ARE REACHED !!!  that are supposed to generate the DDL i.e. the method createSchemaWithHibernate5(LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory). 
So that has something to do with the config or the connection type. When i place a breakpoint on then connection type i see it is of type

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection
```

well that one is extending from "DelegatingConnection" which DOES NOT implement the method getSchema() although it is extending the interface

```
java.sql.Connection
```

which does have the method getSchema().
I am not sure  how this is supposed to work at all, since none of those are final or abstract classes.

I also see that there is another class called

```
org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.
```

How can i force my app to use this one since i see this one indeed DOES implement the method getSchema().

Here is the exception i am running into:

```
2019-04-17 10:06:42.487 DEBUG tito-pc --- [  restartedMain] .i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory : Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [enhanced-table] -> [org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator]
2019-04-17 10:06:43.004 DEBUG tito-pc --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : Database ->
       name : PostgreSQL
    version : 11.2 (Ubuntu 11.2-1.pgdg18.04+1)
      major : 11
      minor : 2
2019-04-17 10:06:43.004 DEBUG tito-pc --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : Driver ->
       name : PostgreSQL JDBC Driver
    version : 42.2.5
      major : 42
      minor : 2
2019-04-17 10:06:43.005 DEBUG tito-pc --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : JDBC version : 4.2
2019-04-17 10:06:43.023  INFO tito-pc --- [  restartedMain] o.h.d.Dialect                            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
2019-04-17 10:06:43.053 DEBUG tito-pc --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.s.IdentifierHelperBuilder      : JDBC driver metadata reported database stores quoted identifiers in neither upper, lower nor mixed case
2019-04-17 10:06:54.515 DEBUG tito-pc --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.DefaultSchemaNameResolver    : Unable to use Java 1.7 Connection#getSchema
2019-04-17 10:06:59.058 DEBUG tito-pc --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentImpl          : Unable to resolve connection default schema
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Use of DefaultSchemaNameResolver requires Dialect to provide the proper SQL statement/command but provided Dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect] did not return anything from Dialect#getCurrentSchemaCommand
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.DefaultSchemaNameResolver$SchemaNameResolverFallbackDelegate.resolveSchemaName(DefaultSchemaNameResolver.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.DefaultSchemaNameResolver.resolveSchemaName(DefaultSchemaNameResolver.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.determineCurrentSchemaName(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:615)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
    .....
```

here is my persistence config:

```
@Profile("Development")
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Order(value=1)
public class PersistenceConfigDevelopment {


    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PersistenceConfigDevelopment.class.getName());

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource dataSourceReadWrite1() {

        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/develpmentTestDb");
        dataSource.setUsername("admin");
        dataSource.setPassword("notABigSecret");
        dataSource.setInitialSize(20);
        dataSource.setMaxActive(-1);


        return dataSource;
    }




    @Bean
    @Primary
    public org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {

        org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(this.dataSourceReadWrite1());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("org.university.");


        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());

        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }   


    @Bean
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        return new Properties() {
            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            {
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect");
                setProperty("hibernate.chach.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider");
                setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");

                setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "false");
                setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "false");

                // isolation level
                setProperty("hibernate.connection.isolation", String.valueOf(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE));


            }
        };
    }       

    @Bean
    public Boolean createSchemaWithHibernate5(LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory) {

        final PostgreSQL95Dialect dialect = new PostgreSQL95Dialect();
        StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = sessionFactory.getConfiguration().getStandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySetting("hibernate.dialect", dialect)
                .build();

        Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry).buildMetadata();

        new SchemaExport() 
                .setOutputFile("db-schema.hibernate5.ddl") 
                .create(EnumSet.of(TargetType.SCRIPT), metadata);

        metadata.buildSessionFactory().close();

        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }


}
```

Because of this stackoverflow post i tried changing the drivers i.e.

[Implementating Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.getSchema()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52745152/implementating-method-org-postgresql-jdbc4-jdbc4connection-getschema)

and tried using "postgresql" maven artifact instead of "org.postgresql" but that did not helped as well.

Any help is really appreciated.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
<!--             <version>${orgpostgresql.version}</version> -->
        </dependency>

<!--         <dependency> -->
<!--             <groupId>postgresql</groupId> -->
<!--             <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId> -->
<!--             <version>${postgresql.version}</version> -->
<!--         </dependency> -->
```

update 17 April

I was able to get rid of the exception  by using another data source i.e. PGSimpleDataSource that also changed the connector to PgConnection, but the DDL is still not being generated. I.e. the file db-schema.hibernate5.ddl is beeing generated but it is empty.

```
@Bean
@Primary
public PGSimpleDataSource dataSourceReadWrite1() {

    PGSimpleDataSource dataSource = new PGSimpleDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/developmentTestDB");
    dataSource.setUser("admin");
    dataSource.setPassword("notABigSecret");


    return dataSource;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem myself

```
11:16:07.675 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - Database ->
       name : PostgreSQL
    version : 10.18 (Ubuntu 10.18-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
      major : 10
      minor : 18
11:16:07.675 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - Driver ->
       name : PostgreSQL Native Driver
    version : PostgreSQL 9.0 JDBC4 (build 801)
      major : 9
      minor : 0
11:16:07.675 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - JDBC version : 4.0
11:16:07.689 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
11:16:07.709 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.IdentifierHelperBuilder - JDBC driver metadata reported database stores quoted identifiers in neither upper, lower nor mixed case
11:16:07.716 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.DefaultSchemaNameResolver - Unable to use Java 1.7 Connection#getSchema
11:16:07.718 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl - Unable to resolve connection default schema
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Use of DefaultSchemaNameResolver requires Dialect to provide the proper SQL statement/command but provided Dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect] did not return anything from Dialect#getCurrentSchemaCommand
```

I had to update the drivers so that it showed

```
11:45:27.477 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - Driver ->
       name : PostgreSQL JDBC Driver
    version : 42.2.23
      major : 42
      minor : 2
```

And I had to change my dialect to

`PostgreSQL10Dialect`